# Kivy change label text with python

Tags: python, label, kivy, updating

I'm semi-OK with Python but brand new to Kivy, I know my problem is referencing the label ID but I can't seem to solve it and searching doesn't seem to give me what I need.

I'm trying to get a label to display the current time, so I know I have the right framework in terms of updating etc but I'm sure its all down to referencing the label ID somehow and its that I'm struggling with?

The following code runs fine, displays the labels etc until I try to update the `label_text.text` at which point i get an error: `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lbl_time'`. I've tried `str(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))` but that doesn't solve it.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, WipeTransition, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import time
from datetime import datetime

class MainScreen(Screen):

def update_time(self):
    lbl_time = ObjectProperty()
    MyTime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    self.lbl_time.text = MyTime

class DetailScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass



root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
    MyScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
    DetailScreen:
    SettingsScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: lbl_time
            text: 'Time' 
            font_size: 60
        Label:
            text: 'Main2'
            font_size: 30
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: 'Bottom'
                font_size: 30
            Label:
                text: 'Bottom1'
                font_size: 30

 <DetailScreen>:
     name: 'details'

 <SettingsScreen>:
     name: 'settings'

 ''')
 class ScreenManagerApp(App):

     def build(self):
         return root_widget

     def on_start(self):
         Clock.schedule_interval(MainScreen.update_time, 1)

 ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

Comment: Change _update_time_ method: **def update_time(self, *args):  MyTime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") self.ids['lbl_time'].text = MyTime**

Comment: Hi - Sorry that doesnt work -->   `File "MyApp.py", line 20, in update_time
     self.ids['lbl_time'].text = MyTime
 AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'ids'`

Comment: You need to call *MainScreen()* for access to his methods `Clock.schedule_interval(MainScreen().update_time, 1)`

Comment: Really appreciate the help - OK so now we are getting somewhere, screen loads with no errors but the label text isn't changing from `'text'`?

Comment: .. Worth noting adding a `print MyTime` updates the CLI as expected so all working logic wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was more of a Python problem rather than a Kivy one. You were calling the `update_time` of the class `MainScreen` class, not of the object/instance of the `MainScreen`. Basically, you would need to save a reference to the object (self.main_screen) in the `build` method, and then use it in the on_start.

```
class ScreenManagerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.main_screen = MainScreen()
        return self.main_screen

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.main_screen.update_time, 1)
```

Also you cannot access id outside of the kv language, i.e. in the python. You have to reference the id by adding a property, e.g. `the_time`:

```
<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    the_time: _id_lbl_time
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: _id_lbl_time
```

A minor problem is that the `update_time()` receives to parameters. Also, there were quite a few weird things in your code, so I couldn't run the code. I fixed all the above in the code below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import time
from datetime import datetime

Builder.load_string('''
<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    the_time: _id_lbl_time
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: _id_lbl_time
            text: 'Time' 
            font_size: 60
 ''')

class MainScreen(Screen):

    def update_time(self, sec):
        MyTime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.the_time.text = MyTime


class ScreenManagerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.main_screen = MainScreen()
        return self.main_screen

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.main_screen.update_time, 1)

ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

Comment: Hey - All working - Thanks - I think the strange things you refer to are the outlines of the screenmanager code I'd started to build, it didn't seem to impact the running of the code so left it until I could sort out the label updating.