# Kivy ScreenManager - Updating label text

Tags: python, label, kivy

I asked a question regarding updating label text ([Kivy change label text with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219868/kivy-change-label-text-with-python)) - it was answered and was working but I've been trying for hours trying to adapt my running code to `ScreenManager` so I can have multiple screens. I've cut down the code to the basic stuff I can't get working.

`ScreenManager` code breaks the solution, I know what the issue is I just can't resolve it. The code is working, text and time updating in the shell but not the labels, I couldn't add `return self.first_screen` to the Kivy `def build` so its not binding to `the_time: _id_lbl_time` - Any help/pointers would be really appreciated.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, WipeTransition, FadeTransition
from  kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


class FirstScreen(Screen):
  def update_time(self, sec):
    MyTime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print  MyTime # to test update_time is called etc
    self.the_time.text = MyTime #<---- self.the_time isn't working

class SecondScreen(Screen):
  def update_text(self, sec):
    MyText = 'New Text'
    print  MyText # to test update_text is called etc
    self.the_set.text = MyText #<---- self.the_set isn't working

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

Builder.load_string('''

<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'first'
    the_time: _id_lbl_time

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label
            id: _id_lbl_time
            text: 'Clock'
            font_size: 30
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'New Here'
                font_size: 20
                size: 200, 50
                size_hint: None, None
                on_release: app.root.current = 'second'

<SecondScreen>:
    name: 'second'
    the_set: _id_lbl_set

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: _id_lbl_set
            text: 'New Here'
            font_size: 30
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Main'
                font_size: 20
                size: 200, 50
                size_hint: None, None
                on_release: app.root.current = 'first'
''')
class ScreenManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(FirstScreen(name='first'))
        sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='second'))
        self.first_screen = FirstScreen()
        self.sec_screen = SecondScreen()
        return sm #<---- I can't return self.first_screen etc here?

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.first_screen.update_time, 1)             # 1 second
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.sec_screen.update_text, 2)

ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't return self.first_screen etc here?

No. There has to be a `ScreenManager` on top of the `Screen` widgets, otherwise it's just a `RelativeLayout` as is its definition in the source code.

You experienced a really common mistake by beginners. You used one instance `FirstScreen()` and `SecondScreen()` for `ScreenManager`(those are visible) and then you created another instances with:

```
self.first_screen = FirstScreen()
self.sec_screen = SecondScreen()
```

which you then used for `Clock`:

```
Clock.schedule_interval(self.first_screen.update_time, 1)
Clock.schedule_interval(self.sec_screen.update_text, 2)
```

and that means `text` properties in instances that actually *aren't added anywhere* as widgets were used for updating. The instances exist, so no error to trigger except the visual one → you don't see the values, because you used wrong instance.

Correct `build()`:

```
def build(self):
    sm = ScreenManager()
    self.first_screen = FirstScreen(name='first')
    self.sec_screen = SecondScreen(name='second')
    sm.add_widget(self.first_screen)
    sm.add_widget(self.sec_screen)
    return sm
```

Comment: Yes that worked - Worth adding for future searchers that `build(self):` needs to `return sm` to return the ScreenManager to actually show it.